# ajax keep running even if Selector class is removed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have 2 forms in 2 different ajax files `ajaxChangeSimple.php` and `ajaxChangAdv.php` . When a user presses a button, it should swap between the 2 forms.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.changeBtn').on('click',function(){
  var yo="<?php echo 'ip_searchmod_'.$unique_qsid; ?>";

  $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"ajaxChangeSimple.php",
    success: function(response){

      $('#' + yo).html(response);
      $('#swapper').addClass('simpleBtn');
      $('#swapper').removeClass('changeBtn');
    }

  });

});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$('.simpleBtn').on('click',function(){
  var yo="<?php echo 'ip_searchmod_'.$unique_qsid; ?>";

  $.ajax({

    type:"POST",
    url:"ajaxChangeAdv.php",
    success: function(response){

      $('#' + yo).html(response);
      $('#swapper').addClass('changeBtn');
      $('#swapper').removeClass('simpleBtn');
    }

  });

});
});

<div id="swapper" class="changeBtn">Change</div>
```

When i click the button for first time, the froms swap and so does the class of `#swapper` .
But after i click it again , even if the class of `#swapper` is now `.simpleBtn` the first ajax function is keep called. ( I checked it via Networking ).

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Event listeners get bound to elements, not to classes. [remove the event listener first](http://api.jquery.com/off/), then change classes, then bind the event listener again

Comment: Or just delegate event to any static container, e.g: `$(document).on('click', '.changeBtn', function(){...});` and then btw, ready handler wrappers become useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your logic delegating event and toggling classes, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click', '.changeBtn, .simpleBtn', function(){
  var yo="<?php echo 'ip_searchmod_'.$unique_qsid; ?>";
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:$(this).hasClass('changeBtn') ? "ajaxChangeSimple.php" : "ajaxChangeAdv.php",
    success: function(response){
      $('#' + yo).html(response);
      $('#swapper').toggleClass('simpleBtn changeBtn');
    }
  });
});
```

It could not work as expected in some cases but i guess in your specfic case, it will.

Comment: that would call the same php file always , wouldn't it ?